# if called function is missing, i want to require any file in __construct function

Tags: php, oop, class

Example class code:

```
<?php 
class example
{
 public function forExample()
 {
  return true;
 }
}

echo example::forExample(); // result "1"
example::notin(); // notin function is not in the our class
?>
```

As seem above; notin function is not in the our class, shortly if called function is not in the class, I want to run the code as follows:

```
<?php 
class example
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  require_once 'try.class.php';
 }
 public function forExample()
 {
  return true;
 }
}
?>
```

And my second question: How do we do this only for the "notin" function?

Comment: If you're trying to redeclare the `example` class, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not idea what you are asking for, but I am quite sure you want `__call` and `__callStatic` magic methods. Those are called if (and only if) you call undefined method upon the instance/class.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: ok then can i get called function's name in __construct?

Comment: @Yusuf I'm not quite sure what are you after. If you want to extend what the class does by requiring another class, it won't work. That's not how `require` is used.